# using HTTP/1.0 proxy server for browser

Tags: http, proxy-server

I am writing http proxy server with support http/1.0. I use my proxy server in browser (google chrome). Proxy gets request something like `GET www.site.com HTTP/1.1` and sends response `HTTP/1.0 505 HTTP Version Not Supported`. After that browser show me that error. However I expect that browser will make re-request with http/1.0 version (for example `GET www.site.com HTTP/1.0`). Whether I should send another response in order to get desired behaviour from browser? or it isn't possible? How to make the browser to work with http/1.0 proxy-server?

Comment: Also see https://superuser.com/a/1263101/78897

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, this depends on your browser. If you use Microsoft Internet Explorer, this might help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811262/EN-US

I haven't found anything about http protocol negotiation. A client *could* issue a "HTTP OPTIONS" request in order to detect the server's abilities, but there is no such requirement from the [RFC 2616, Section 19.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-19.6). There's only an *expectation* for clients to understand lower protocol versions.